# Why is my footer behaving this way? - fixed content, non fixed bg

Tags: html, css, footer

I have a php website that pulled it's header and footer from functions, everything is working fine - except for the footer display. I have attached the code relevant and the URL for review. Any help on getting the footer to stay attached to the bottom and have the content within the containers of the footer sections (left outter, left inner, right inner, right outter and bottom (footer small).

html portion:

```
<?php
function displayFooter() {
?>
</div>
<footer>
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom footer">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row-fluid"> 
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                     <ul>
                    <li><a href="news.php">News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="press.php">Press</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contactus.php">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="privacy.php">Privacy</a></li>
                    <li><a href="terms.php">Terms Of Use</a></li>
                     </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                    <h2 class="twitterfooter">Tweets</h2>
                    <!-- TODO - ADD FOOTER APP FOR RECENT TWEETS HERE -->
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                   <h2>We Accept</h2>
                     <ul class="payment-logos">
                        <li class="visa">Visa</li>
                        <li class="mc">Mastercard</li>
                        <li class="disc">Discover</li>
                        <li class="amex">AMEX</li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                   <div id="newsletter">
                       TODO - add newsletter integration
                   </div>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
 <small>Copyright &copy; <?php echo date('o')?> Information Security     Education. All Rights Reserved. <span> Website Engineered by <a     href="www.steelcitydev.com"><img src="/dev/ise/images/scd.png" alt="Steel     City Developers, llc" width="32" height="12"/></a></span></small>
</div>
</footer>
```

here is the relevant css:

```
footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 355px;
  background: url(/dev/ise/images/footer-bg.png); 
  background-repeat: repeat;
}

footer span {
  background: rgba(34, 34, 34, 1); /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(34, 34, 34, 1) 0%, rgba(71, 71, 71, 1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(34, 34, 34, 1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(71, 71, 71, 1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(34, 34, 34, 1) 0%,rgba(71, 71, 71, 1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(34, 34, 34, 1) 0%,rgba(71, 71, 71, 1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(34, 34, 34, 1) 0%,rgba(71, 71, 71, 1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(34, 34, 34, 1) 0%,rgba(71, 71, 71, 1) 100%); /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='rgba(34, 34, 34, 1)', endColorstr='rgba(71, 71, 71, 1)',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  height: 70px;
  border-top: 3px solid rgba(79, 79, 79, 1);
}
```

and the dev url is http://steelcitydevstudios.com/dev/ise/login.php

i really need the content inside the footer to be stuck on the footer - right now the footer background (not small) will slide up and down with the page (when i scroll up/down). I would like it so that you see the footer at the bottom of the page (if there is relevant content to do so)  and when you scroll you would be able to view the entirety of the footer and content.

Thank you in advance guys, im kinda stuck on this one.

Comment: hi, if your problem is the CSS, did you try this : footer { ... background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; } ? does it do what you want?

Comment: I tried to add the background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; and it has not changed anything.

Comment: Off-topic: code for gradient was generated with Colorzilla, which isn't as relevant as before. According to [caniuse for CSS Gradients](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients), you can safely remove `-o-` and `-ms-` prefix, at least and probably `-moz-` too. Even old Presto-powered Opera 12 removed prefix, same for IE10 and current Firefox Extended Stable Release (ESR) also don't use one (it's Fx 31 with critical updates though the previous one is Fx 24 but it didn't receive critical updates  since approx. october, 2014 so well...) tl;dr [Autoprefixer](https://css-tricks.com/autoprefixer/) FTW

Comment: Thank you for the comment - i will update the gradient. Anybody have any advice on footer?

Comment: You have several issues :
- The "position :fixed" of the div inside footer is causing problems. Try to have a "position: fixed;" on footer and leave the "div" inside to natively position itself. 
- When using position: absolute, it's always better to have the parent's position to "relative"

Comment: Do not hesitate to use your browser's inspector to debug/test/experiment. Just right click the element or div section and hit Inspect Element from your browser, you can then play around with contents until you find out where the problem comes from

Comment: @Braza , unfortunately I changed the position relative to position absolute for the footer - then the inside components I let inherit their position and it didnt have much effect on the way it lays out as far as showing the content of the footer and having it 'scroll' with the page. The footer background is stagnant and is actually how i want / need it to appear .. Now if I was just able to get the content to behave the same.